# python equivalent to "grepl" R with condition

Tags: python, r

The following is the R code. May I know what is the python equivalent to the code below. Specially the

```
grepl("dog|cat", data$animal)
```

part of the code

```
data <- data.frame(animal = sample(c("cat","dog","bird",'doggy','kittycat'), 
                                       10, replace = T)) 
ifelse(grepl("dog|cat", data$animal), "keep", "discard")
```

Comment: What does the python data look like? A list, a panda data frame? Please add the python code that sets up sample data.

Comment: Data is in list.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re` for regular expressions, loop over the animals, and test if there's a match by comparing with `None`:

```
>>> animal = ["cat","dog","doggy","kittycat","bird","dog"]
>>> import re
>>> [re.search("cat|dog",a) is not None for a in animal]
[True, True, True, True, False, True]
```